# What are the differences between running a command in bash and running a command in a Makefile?

Tags: c++, bash, makefile

I have this command that compiles my program.

```
c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -pthread -std=c++11 -fPIC $(python3 -m pybind11 --includes) f1.cpp f2.cpp -o exemple$(python3-config --extension-suffix)
```

I created the following Makefile.

```
test:
    c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -pthread -std=c++11 -fPIC $(python3 -m pybind11 --includes) f1.cpp f2.cpp -o exemple$(python3-config --extension-suffix)
```

The command will succeed if ran from terminal but make will fail.

It fails with the error

```
pybind11/pybind11.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
```

This file is supposed to be imported with `$(python3 -m pybind11 --includes)` in the command.

I thought that commands in Makefile were executed much like a bash script.

What are the differences between running a command in bash and running a command in a Makefile ?

Comment: The makefile interprets `$(python3 ...)` as a makefile variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Makefiles run commands in `/bin/sh` (by default).  That can sometimes make a difference, if you're using bash features; but you're not so that doesn't matter.

The issue here is that the `$` character is special to make: it introduces make variables.  If you want to pass a `$` to the shell you have to double it:

```
test:
        c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -pthread -std=c++11 -fPIC $$(python3 -m pybind11 --includes) f1.cpp f2.cpp -o exemple$$(python3-config --extension-suffix)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another variant `$(shell bash_command)`

```
test:
    c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -pthread -std=c++11 -fPIC $(shell python3 -m pybind11 --includes) f1.cpp f2.cpp -o exemple$(shell python3-config --extension-suffix)
```

Answer (score 1):

The more portable way of inserting a command result as a part of the current command in shell is using ``  instead of `$(python3 -m pybind11 --includes)`. Make does not interpret such quotes.

```
test:
    c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -pthread -std=c++11 -fPIC `python3 -m pybind11 --includes` f1.cpp f2.cpp -o exemple`python3-config --extension-suffix`
```

Comment: Ack.  This may be more portable, but it is digging into best practice from 1992 or so.  Much better to do `$$( cmd )` and just escape the `$`.

Comment: I prefer two chars **\`\`** that are not three $, (, ) and it is more important for me, those two chars are typed by one hand without pressing Shift and without switching the hands because of $ and ( are placed on different halves of the keyboard.