# What are the differences between running a command in a shell (sh or bash) and in a Makefile?

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, sh

The file `myfile` does not exist.

In a shell, `rm myFile` returns an error : it is OK

In a shell, `test -f myFile && rm myFile` does not return an error : it is OK

But in a simple Makefile :

```
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    test -f myFile && rm myFile
```

returns an error.

I know how to avoid it : `-test -f myFile && rm myFile` (errors are still there but ignored) or `$(shell test -f myFile1 && rm myFile1)` (There is no error, job is done but ***'nothing to do'*** is displayed) or `rm -rf` or ...

But, I would like to understand why `test -f myFile && rm myFile` does not return an error in a shell but it returns an error in a Makefile.

I read this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66907116/7462275). But the behaviour is the same in a `bash` shell or in a `sh` shell.

##### Answers are in comments.

Comment: If the file is not there, the command `test -f myFile && rm myFile` will return with a non-zero return statement as the test command will fail. If you want it to work as expected, you need to add it in an `if` statement.

Comment: @kvantour. Thanks for answer.  I think I have understood. In shell, if the file does not exist, a non-zero value is returned `echo $?`. But there is no error message displayed because this is not an error. In a Makefile, a non-zero return is considered as an error whatever the command used.

Comment: Exactly. In essence, even the non-zero return state in shell is considered an error. It just does not inform you about it. Shell give the user the flexibility to deal with it, while Makefiles are extremely strict and work under the assumption _in case there has been an error, it cannot be assumed that continuation of operations will be possible__

Comment: A shorter form : `test -f myFile && rm myFile || true`

Comment: Or `rm -f myFile`

Comment: @Philippe. `|| true` : Good trick !!!

Comment: @Philippe. I agree for the `-f` option. It works with `rm` but other commands have not such option.

Comment: @Philippe the form `test -f myFile && rm myFile || true` will return `true` if the file exist but the `rm` failed for whatever reason (eg. protected file). The following would actually be better `rm -f myFile; test -f myFile` might be the best solution. If that failed, something went really wrong.

Comment: @kvantour `rm -f myFile; test -f myFile` will always fail, unless `rm` failed and the file is still there.

Comment: @Stef1611 In that case, try this `test ! -f myFile || rm myFile`

Comment: @RenaudPacalet. I agree. I could not edit my comment so I deleted it. I should have written :  So I will not use `test` alone in Makefile but inside an `if` `then` construct. `if [ -f myFile1 ]; then rm myFile1; fi`